# Python 3 - adding an integer to a list and printing it in a format

Tags: python, python-3.x

My list is laid out like this:

```
1st name, last name, wins, losses
zac,kop,5,6
jack,mop,0,11
farth,tal,11,0
darth,vader,2,9
nump,kk,1,10
```

My code is this:

```
def points():
    template = "|{0:30}|{1:30}|{2:30}|{3:30}|{4:30}"
    lol = template.format("1st name: ","2nd Name: ", "won: ", "lost: ","points: ")
    print(lol)

    with open(r'prac2.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            data = line.split(',')

            if data[2] >= ('1'):
                poin = (int(float(data[2]))) * 3)
                add_list = data.insert(4,poin)
                print('|{0[0]:<30}|{0[1]:<30}|{0[2]:<30}|{0[3]:<30}|{0[4]:<30}'.format(data))

points()
```

The code is supposed to print out only the info of the players with at least 1 win.

Each win is 3 points, so the program has to calculate each players points and display it along side their information in a table.

The problem is that when it prints the points its on a newline indented, only the last player on the list isn't effected by this problem. Please help.

Comment: Your list doesn't look like a list.

Comment: Strings compare lexicographically.  If you want a numerical comparison: ```int(data[2]) >= 1```.  I'm sure this is a duplicate question, I just haven't found it yet.

Comment: `if data[2] >= ('1')` alphanum comparison. Is it deliberate?

Comment: `poin = (int(float(data[2]))) * 3)` has one too many closing brackets at`data[2])))`.  The surrounding brackets can also be removed.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons

Comment: just use RDBMS...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if data[2] >= ('1'):
    poin = int(float(data[2])) * 3
    data[3] = data[3].strip()
    add_list = data.insert(4,poin)
```

The last string in your split line contains a newline. You need to `strip()` it.

or, when you read the line:

```
data = line.strip().split(',')
```

Which gives you what you want:

```
>>> points()
|1st name: |2nd Name: |won:      |lost:     |points:   
|zac       |kop       |5         |6         |15        
|farth     |tal       |11        |0         |33        
|darth     |vader     |2         |9         |6  
|nump      |kk        |1         |10        |3
```

Also relevant:

```
template = "|{0:<30}|{1:<30}|{2:<30}|{3:<30}|{4:<30}"
...
print(template.format(*data))
```

works and actually uses the template you designed.

`*data` [unpacks](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) the list into its individual components, so you don't have to subscript them in, equivalent, in this case, to doing:

`print(template.format(data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3], data[4]))`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you don't remove the line end characters from the last element of the line! Right before printing, after you inserted the points, `data` looks like this:

```
['zac', 'kop', '5', '6\n', 15]
```

To fix it, you can add [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) to your `data = ...` line to this:

```
data = line.strip().split(',')
```

Some more points:

- don't compare strings when you want to compare numbers
- skip the header line, e.g. using `next(file)` before the loop
- no point in casting `wins` to `float` and then int, just use `int`
- instead of `insert(4, ...)` just use `append` to add to the end of the list

Comment: @wwii Using `end=''` won't remove a `\n` in the middle of the string.

Answer (score 1):

At least one of your problems is data type:

> ```
>  if data[2] >= ('1'):
> ```

Here you have two strings and are comparing them lexicographically.  You really want two numbers and to compare them arithmetically.

Without any error handling, that would look like this:

```
if int(data[2]) >= 1:
```